# I called a hello prototype inside load prototype but its says undefined ot hello is not a function

Tags: javascript

I called a hello prototype inside load prototype but its says undefined ot hello is not a function

```
function Myfunc(){}

Myfunc.prototype.load = function(){
  let html =`hello i am ${this.hello()}`
  return html;
}

Myfunc.prototyoe.hello= function(){
  let head =`i am foo`
  return head;
}
```

Comment: Typo. `Myfunc.prototyoe`

Comment: @nircraft if a question includes a typo in code, the author should be the one to correct it.  Not editors.  The typo may be the entire problem.

Comment: got it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your obvious typo, you forgot to instantiate your constructor function.

```js
function Myfunc(){}

Myfunc.prototype.load = function(){
  let html =`hello i am ${this.hello()}`
  return html;
}

Myfunc.prototype.hello= function(){
  let head =`i am foo`
  return head;
}

// You need to instantiate Myfunc
const func = new Myfunc();

console.log(func.load());
```

Comment: I instantiate Myfunc earlier but it was not working